# Why do seekp/tellp behave differently in append mode?

Tags: c++, c++11

I need to append a line to an existing file and then add one more value to that line. I'm making use of the `seekp` and `tellp` functions for that. Consider the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fstream>

int main(){
    //file position
    long long opos;
    //output file
    std::ofstream outfile;

    //open new file
    outfile.open("outfile.dat"); 
    outfile<<"1\t2\t3"<<std::endl;
    opos = outfile.tellp();
    outfile.seekp (opos-1);
    outfile<< "\t4" <<std::endl;
    outfile.close();

    //appending existing file 
    outfile.open("outfile.dat", std::ios::app); 
    outfile<<"1\t2\t3"<<std::endl;
    opos = outfile.tellp();
    outfile.seekp (opos-1);
    outfile<< "\t4" <<std::endl;
    outfile.close();    
}
```

It consists of two blocks. First, I open a new file, write the line `1 2 3\n` to it, then go back one step and overwrite the `\n` with `\t4`. This works. However, when I open the file in append mode (second block), it appears that `seekp` lost track of the position. This is the output:

```
$ cat outfile.dat 
1   2   3   4
1   2   3
    4
```

My question is whether this is the expected behavior and if it is, how to properly add the extra value `\t4`to the existing line that works both simple open and in append mode?

**Edit:** based on the helpful comments below, changing the second file opening to

```
outfile.open("outfile.dat", std::ios::ate | std::ios::in);
```

appears to solve the problem. `ate` seeks to the end of the file only at opening as opposed to `app` which indeed seeks to the end after each write operation. The output now is

```
$ cat outfile.dat 
1   2   3   4
1   2   3   4
```

Comment: `app` seek to the end of stream before each write.  So, yes, that is expected behavior.

Comment: [See this link for more information](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ofstream/open)

Comment: @Eljay You should post that as the answer. Like @Botond, I was not aware that `app` seeks to the end before each write. I thought it was only after opening. So `seekp()` really does not have any effect on a file opened in `app` mode. Well, we learn something new everyday :-)

Comment: Wait until you find out that [there is no difference between `seekp` and `seekg` in file streams.](http://eel.is/c++draft/file.streams#filebuf.general-3.3)

Comment: If you're in append mode you don't need the `tellp()` or `seekp()` at all. You're already at the right place.

Comment: @user207421 I agree, except that I do the line writing from a separate function and then I have to append a few values separately.